# Control with Selenium a dynamic table created with javascript with Selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I would like to know if it would be possible to select the menu item from one created almost entirely with javascrip with selenium. As html tags for this table are only available in view source

```
<table id = "table_id"> <tr> <td> <script> *** </script> </td> </tr> </table>
```

and instead of asterisks there is a javascript that dynamically creates this menu with

```
with (milonic = new menuname ('menu_name'))
```

and aI () strings. When you click on a menu item, a submenu opens. My question - how can i for example select item no.2 from the menu and then item no.3 from the submenu? Such a construction as

```
driver.find_element_by_id ('table_id').click ()
```

does not help, only the menu item in the middle is selected, but not clicked.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: Sorry, this page needs authorization with username and password, i cannot publish the private login data of our company.

Comment: I understand. But without this I don't think it's possible to help you

Comment: Excuse me, may i ask - you mean that this problem needs java programming or debugging in the browser? I can do it in principle and know a little bit of java scripts. Do you can say me, whether i have thought correctly?

Comment: I just mean that to know what element to click and what to select we need to see the web page, open the F12 and see exactly what elements are there, what are their unique locators etc. 
Generally, without this, the answer is "Yes". You always can click some element to open the menu and there will be possible to locate each and any of the options to select there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got solution, i used F12 in FF and found all the links i needed. The instability can be solved with this code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)
wait.until (EC.element_to_be_clickable ((By.ID, "id"))). click ()
```